# First order ODE, separation of variables, problem with (easy?) integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve an initial value problem of the form
$x'(t) = \frac{t}{2x(t+1)}$?

I write the RHS as $\frac{1}{2x} \frac{t}{t+1}$ which leads by separation of variables to $x^2 + C = \int 2x dx = \int \frac{t}{t+1} dt$.

Is this ok? I am a bit ashamed to ask (because it is probably obvious) but what is the integral on the RHS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int\frac{t}{t+1}dt=\int\frac{t+1-1}{t+1}dt=\int(1-\frac{1}{t+1})dt=t-\log|t+1|+C$$

Comment: of course, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Another way to do the same thing: let u= t+ 1.  The dt= du and t= u- 1.  The integral becomes $\int\frac{u- 1}{u} du= \int \left(1- \frac{1}{u}\right)du$ giving the same result.